# Ajax checkbox not updating url on check

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var data = {},
        fdata = [],
        loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location})[0];

    $('input[tpye="checkbox"]').each(function(i){
        if(this.checked){
            if(!data.hasOwnProperty(this.name)){
                data[this.name] = [];
            }
            data[this.name].push(this.value);
        }
    });

    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        fdata[k] = [v.join(',')];
    });

    fdata = fdata.join('&');
    $.post('/wines/all-wines/', fdata);
    console.log(fdata);

    if(history.pushState){
        history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname+'?'+fdata);
    }
});
```

```
 <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="rowElem">
                <input type="checkbox" name="country" value="1" id="">
                <label>Color #1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="rowElem">
                <input type="checkbox" name="country" value="2" id="">
                <label>Color #2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="rowElem">
                <input type="checkbox" name="country" value="3" id="">
                <label>Color #3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm using laravel thats why i'm passing X-CSRF token. What i want to achieve is when user clicks on one or more checkboxes it automatically change url to something like this : link.com/products/all-products?country=1,2,3,4,5

but after clicking on checkboxes it only change url to : link.com/products/all-products? and thats mainly it. What could be wrong in the code? Thank you very much!

Comment: There's a typo in your code, `input[tpye="checkbox"]`

Comment: Do you only want to change the URL in the browser? or store the url when the user click on some element go to this URL?

Comment: I have changed that type to correct version. And yes after a click on one or more checkboxes i want to change the link reload the page. :)) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what nbkHope pointed out you need the following:

```
$.each(data, function(k, v){
    fdata[k] = [v.join(',')];
});

var countryArr = fdata["country"];
fdata = countryArr.join('&');
```

Your array looks like this: {country: Array()}, so you need to get country out of fdata and then call join.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join